# importance sampling strategies

Tags: logistic, importance-sampling, logistic-curve

I am trying to approximate the expectation of the "complete-data likelihood" with respect to the distribution of some missing data, and I am having some trouble. This expectation can be written as 
$$
\int p(\mathbf{y} \mid \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{\beta})f(\mathbf{x}) d\mathbf{x}_{1:n} = \int \prod_{i=1}^np(y_i \mid \mathbf{x}_i, \mathbf{\beta})f(\mathbf{x}_i) d\mathbf{x}_{1:n}
$$
where

1. $p(y_i \mid \mathbf{x}_i, \mathbf{\beta}) = \sigma(\mathbf{x}_i^T\beta)^{y_i} [1-\sigma(\mathbf{x}_i^T\beta)]^{1-y_i}$
2. $f(\mathbf{x}_i)$ is chosen, so let's not make any assumptions about what it is yet. The $\sigma$ function is the inverse logit, or sigmoid function: $\sigma(r) = e^r/(1+e^r)$.

You can use importance sampling by picking an importance density $q(\mathbf{x}^s \mid \mathbf{y})$, simulating $N_s$ times from it, and calculating:
$$
\sum_{s = 1}^{N_s}  \frac{p(\mathbf{y} \mid \mathbf{x}^s, \mathbf{\beta})f(\mathbf{x}^s)}{q(\mathbf{x}^s \mid \mathbf{y})} \bigg/ N_s.
$$

I am interested in reducing relative variance, and not getting all of these $-\infty$s. Are there well-known or popular strategies to accomplish this? Maybe I can simulate $\mathbf{x}^s$ so that all of these $\mathbf{x}_i^T\beta$s are constrained to be close to $0$.

Edit: perhaps I should be more clear about this: this is a logistic regression model with missing data, not a state space model. The phrase “complete data likelihood” could’ve been misleading as it means two different things in these two contexts. Also, it could’ve been misleading that I simplified notation for $f$, as it doesn’t have anything denoting missing and observed subvectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importance sampling is notorious for falling afoul of dimensionality, the so called [curse of dimension(ality)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality). This means that a direct frontwise importance sampling attack in this latent variable setting cannot work.

The standard approach is to use instead [sequential importance sampling](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/228569/7224), also called [sequential Monte Carlo](https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~doucet/doucet_defreitas_gordon_smcbookintro.pdf) or [particle filtering](https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~doucet/doucet_defreitas_gordon_smcbookintro.pdf), where an importance sample is created for each $\mathbf{x}_i$ in the sequence $\mathbf{x}_{1:n}$, targeting the density proportional to $$p(y_i \mid \mathbf{x}_i, \mathbf{\beta})f(\mathbf{x}_i |\mathbf{x}_{1:{i-1}})$$and estimating its normalising constant from that sample.

Comment: Yes, thanks, (+1), I started in on this a few days ago as resampling might help some in this non-time-series context, but I'm still interested in the shape of this specific $p$. That's still an issue with these strategies, too. On the other hand, resampling might just add noise, because there’s nothing to learn from, going row to row.

Comment: Oh you're referring to the "data-tempering" thing. Sorry this took me a while to grasp, I'm usually in the state space model setting. Thanks again.